# Why does PDFBox return image dimension of size 0 x 0

Tags: java, pdfbox

To find the actual size taken by an image on a PDF, I use PDFBox, and I followed what is described in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35043154/6351897). So basically I call

```
 // Computes the image actual location and dimensions
 PrintImageLocations renderer = new PrintImageLocations();

 for (int i = 0; i < pageLimit; ++i) {
        PDPage page = pdf.getPage(i);

        renderer.processPage(page);
 }
```

and the PrintImageLocations() is taken from [this PDFBox code example](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/pdfbox/trunk/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/util/PrintImageLocations.java).

Yet with a PDF document that I use for test (generated by GPL Ghostscript 910 (ps2write) from an image found [on Wikipedia](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b1/NorthwoodsMemorandum.jpg/185px-NorthwoodsMemorandum.jpg)), the image size reported is 0 x 0 (although the PDF can be imported into Gimp or Libre Office Draw).

So I'd like to know if the code I am currently using is reliable or not to find image size, and what could make it not find the right image size ?

The PDF used for this test [can be found here](https://files.fm/u/udvgszyv#_)

==========

Edit :
Following @Itai comment, it appears that **the condition `if ("Do".equals(operation))` gets not evaluated** because there no such operation is invoked. Consequently the `processOperator` from the super class is invoked.

The only operations that are invoked are (I added `System.err.println("Processing " + operation);` before the condition in the overriden `processOperator` method) :

Processing q
Processing cm
Processing gs
Processing q
Processing re
Processing W
Processing n
Processing rg
Processing re
Processing f
Processing cs
Processing scn
Processing re
Processing f
Processing Q
Processing Q

==========

Any hints appreciated,

Comment: Are all sizes reported as 0? What is the complete output?

Comment: @Itai it reports the actual size on other PDFs. Even testing http://www.hourofthetime.com/1-LF/December2012/Hour_Of_The_Time_12282012-Northwoods_Justification_For_US_Military_Intervention.pdf which looks alike (as far as the first page is concerned) shows the right size.

Comment: I meant - are all sizes *for that picture* reported as 0? It should print the pixel size, unit size, actual size etc. Are all of them 0?

Comment: Good guess @Itai! Indeed the `if (xobject instanceof PDImageXObject) {` gets not evaluated. And zero is the initialized value that I use.

Comment: There is no "Do" operations, so the operations get processed in the super class. Here are the operations that are processed :
Processing q
Processing cm
Processing gs
Processing q
Processing re
Processing W
Processing n
Processing rg
Processing re
Processing f
Processing cs
Processing scn
Processing re
Processing f
Processing Q
Processing Q

Comment: The image is neither immediately added from the page content nor from an embedded XObject. Instead it is used inside a pattern. The example code, though, only inspects the content of the page and embedded (probably nested) XObjects. Thus, your image is not found. This, by the way, also is the reason why you can't easily export the image from Adobe Reader...

Comment: @mkl is there a workaround to that ?

Comment: I'm looking into that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already have found out yourself, the reason for the 0x0 output is that the code from `PrintImageLocations` as-is cannot find the image at all.

`PrintImageLocations` does not find the image because it only looks for image uses in the page content and in form XObjects (also nested) used in the page content. In the file at hand, on the other hand, the image is drawn inside a tiling **Pattern** content which is used to *fill* an area in the page content.

To allow PDFBox to find this image, we have to extend the `PrintImageLocations` class a bit to also descent into pattern content streams, e.g. like this:

```java
class PrintImageLocationsImproved extends PrintImageLocations {
    public PrintImageLocationsImproved() throws IOException {
        super();

        addOperator(new SetNonStrokingColor());
        addOperator(new SetNonStrokingColorN());
        addOperator(new SetNonStrokingDeviceCMYKColor());
        addOperator(new SetNonStrokingDeviceGrayColor());
        addOperator(new SetNonStrokingDeviceRGBColor());
        addOperator(new SetNonStrokingColorSpace());
    }

    @Override
    protected void processOperator(Operator operator, List<COSBase> operands) throws IOException {
        String operation = operator.getName();
        if (fillOperations.contains(operation)) {
            PDColor color = getGraphicsState().getNonStrokingColor();
            PDAbstractPattern pattern = getResources().getPattern(color.getPatternName());
            if (pattern instanceof PDTilingPattern) {
                processTilingPattern((PDTilingPattern) pattern, null, null);
            }
        }
        super.processOperator(operator, operands);
    }

    final List<String> fillOperations = Arrays.asList("f", "F", "f*", "b", "b*", "B", "B*");
}
```

*([ExtractImageLocations](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-pdfbox2/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/pdfbox2/extract/ExtractImageLocations.java#L132) inner class `PrintImageLocationsImproved`)*

The tiling pattern in the document at hand is used as a pattern color for filling, not stroking. Thus, `PrintImageLocationsImproved` has to register operator listeners for non-stroking color operators to have the fill color correctly updated in the graphics state.

`processOperator` before delegating to the `PrintImageLocations` implementation now first checks whether the operator is a *fill* operation. In that case it inspects the current fill color. If it is a pattern color, `processOperator` initiates the `processTilingPattern` handling defined in `PDFStreamEngine` which  starts a nested analysis of the pattern content stream and so eventually lets the `PrintImageLocationsImproved` find the image.

Using `PrintImageLocationsImproved` like this

```java
try (   PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(...)    )
{
    PrintImageLocations printer = new PrintImageLocationsImproved();
    int pageNum = 0;
    for( PDPage page : document.getPages() )
    {
        pageNum++;
        System.out.println( "Processing page: " + pageNum );
        printer.processPage(page);
    }
}
```

*([ExtractImageLocations](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-pdfbox2/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/pdfbox2/extract/ExtractImageLocations.java#L95) test `testExtractLikeHelloWorldImprovedFromTopSecret`)*

for your PDF file, therefore, will find the image:

```
Processing page: 1
*******************************************************************
Found image [R8]
position in PDF = 39.0, 102.48 in user space units
raw image size  = 1209, 1640 in pixels
displayed size  = 516.3119, 700.3752 in user space units
displayed size  = 7.1709986, 9.727433 in inches at 72 dpi rendering
displayed size  = 182.14336, 247.0768 in millimeters at 72 dpi rendering
```

#### Beware,

this is not not perfect fix, more a proof-of-concept and work-around, as it does neither properly restrict the pattern to the area actually filled nor return multiple finds for an area large enough to require multiple pattern tiles to fill. Nonetheless, it returns an image match for the file at hand..

Comment: Thanks a lot @mkl, I will give it a try! By the way how to you inspect such PDFs, in order to reveal how they are laid out / organized ?

Comment: There are tools to inspect PDFs like PDFBox PDFDebugger an iText RUPS. And some details already can be seen in a simple text viewer. You need some background knowledge in the PDF format, though.

Comment: Hey thank you @mkl, I didn't know PDFBox existed as standalone java app (https://pdfbox.apache.org/1.8/commandline.html)!